# How to pass tuple of lists and integers as a key to dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make a dictionary. Key contains list of lists and a number followed by a value.
For example,

```
matrix = {
([[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 10, 3], [20, 21, 18, 12]], 3): 1, 
([[ 0, 0, 10, 0], [1, 0, 0, 5], [ 0, 0, 0, 4]], 1): 2, 
([[ 0, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 10, 0]], 3): 3
}
```

The above declaration is causing the following error.

```
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How to make such dictionary?

Comment: Lists a not hashable, they can not be used as dictionary keys. Tuples on the other side are hashable and would work.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use lists as keys. You can use tuples however:

```
matrix = {
    (((1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 4, 10, 3), (20, 21, 18, 12)), 3): 1, 
    (((0, 0, 10, 0), (1, 0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 0, 4)), 1): 2, 
    (((0, 0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 10, 0)), 3): 3
}
```

Tuples are immutable collections, and as such can be hashed, which is a requirement for a dictionary key

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) objects as dictionary keys, which are immutables (mostly).

A tuple is indeed a hashable object however it contains a list and therefore you can't use it as a dictionary key.
You might want to cast each list to tuple before you use it as a dictionary key.

Answer (score 1):

Lists cannot be used as keys for dictionaries. A good work around is to use [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) for a string representation:

```
matrix = {
repr(([[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 10, 3], [20, 21, 18, 12]], 3)): 1,
repr(([[ 0, 0, 10, 0], [1, 0, 0, 5], [ 0, 0, 0, 4]], 1)): 2,
repr(([[ 0, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 10, 0]], 3)): 3
}
print(matrix)
```

Output:

```
{'([[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 10, 3], [20, 21, 18, 12]], 3)': 1, 
 '([[0, 0, 10, 0], [1, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 4]], 1)': 2, 
 '([[0, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 10, 0]], 3)': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyList(list):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self[0])
```

you should make every list include sublist to MyList Object

Comment: i doubt it will be efficient